# Isolates in Flutter - Where can I place the isolates inside my Flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have some confusion regarding how Isolates can be used inside a Flutter application.

If we go through the documentation, It is said that functions that you pass inside the isolates should only be declared as top-level functions. Does that mean we cannot declare them inside a class ?

I created a class TestIsolate inside my lib/business_logic/bloc folder.

```
class TestIsolate {
  Future<void> handle(int _m) async {
    final response = ReceivePort();
    await Isolate.spawn(_isolate, response.sendPort);
    final sendPort = await response.first as SendPort;
    final answer = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send([_m, answer.sendPort]);
    await answer.first.then((p) {
      log(p);
    });
  }

  static void _isolate(SendPort _initialReplyTo) {
    final port = ReceivePort();
    _initialReplyTo.send(port.sendPort);
    port.listen((message) {
      final data = message[0] as int;
      final send = message[1] as SendPort;
      send.send(_syncHandle(data));
    });
  }
}

Future<String> _syncHandle(int data) async {
  return 'done - $data';
}
```

I then called `await TestIsolate.handle(15)` upon an onTap event from my presentation layer which worked like a charm.

Am I doing this correctly ? If yes, can we call handle() placed inside TestIsolate class as a top-level function?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation where you read that?

Comment: Yes. https://blog.codemagic.io/understanding-flutter-isolates/ : Refer to "Create a new isolate using Isolate.spawn()"
 It says - "The function passed to the isolate spawn() must be a top-level function *(a function that is not within the boundary of a class) or a static method."

Comment: "top level function or static method" - yours is the latter

Comment: Got it. Totally forgot there's a ")". Thanks for the clarification. One more thing, Can I use one isolate for handling multiple async function calls or should I create different ones for each respective call. What's the better approach?

Comment: Dart 2.19 (published yesterday) changed this radically.  See Isolate.run for details.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. The [source you reference](https://blog.codemagic.io/understanding-flutter-isolates/) (which I will point out is an article, not documentation) says:

> The function passed to the isolate `spawn()` must be a top-level function *(a function that is not within the boundary of a class) or a static method.

You are spawning an isolate with an entry point of `_isolate()`, which is a static method. So, according to your source, that is ok.

However, it may be the case that your source is outdated. According to the [changelog for Dart 2.15](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#dart-vm-1):

> Allow closures both in inter-isolate messages as well as as entrypoints in `Isolate.spawn(<entrypoint>, ...)` calls. Closures and their enclosing context may need to be copied in this process. The enclosing context is - as with normal messages - verified to only contain objects that are sendable.
>
> Note of caution: The Dart VM's current representation of enclosing variables in closures can make closures hang on to more variables than strictly needed. Using such closures in inter-isolate communication can therefore lead to copying of larger transitive object graphs. If the extended transitive closure includes objects that are illegal to send, the sending will fail.

It would appear that closure (and non-static method) arguments to `Isolate.spawn()` were introduced after your source article was written.

As the changelog cautions though, you do want to be cognizant of the memory copying that will occur.

Further references:

- [Is DartDocs about the entry of Isolate.spawn wrong or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73778870)

Comment: Hello Chuck. Thanks for taking the time. I'm still in learning phase and would really like to understand the closure and non-static method thing. What is the conclusion here and what's the best approach ? Should the entry point be a static method or a non static method ? Also, what is a closure ?

Comment: Hello Divyam. First, isolates are a somewhat advanced use of Dart. Are you certain you need them? Asynchronous operations are insufficient for your use case? Second, you can read about closures in Dart [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions).

Comment: Hello Chuck. I'm just experimenting with isolates..Finding out, how must I use them in case it's needed. What is the best approach and so on..